# Android custom dialog url image not displaying?

Tags: android, dialog, imageview, image-loading

Here is my code, I trying to show URL image in ImageView it is not working,

mycode:

```
        CustomDialog alert = new CustomDialog(this,  R.style.myCoolDialog);
        alert.setContentView(R.layout.item_details);                        
        ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(this);

        ImageView image1=(ImageView)alert.findViewById(R.id.details_image1);
        ImageView image2=(ImageView)alert.findViewById(R.id.details_image2);
        ImageView image3=(ImageView)alert.findViewById(R.id.details_image3);

        image1.setTag(listFilltered.get(position).getAttr4());
        image2.setTag(listFilltered.get(position).getAttr12());
        image3.setTag(listFilltered.get(position).getAttr3());

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(listFilltered.get(position).getAttr4(), image1);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(listFilltered.get(position).getAttr12(), image2);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(listFilltered.get(position).getAttr3(), image3);

alert.show();
```

In customDialog:

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog {

    public CustomDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
     }
   }
```

I'm done everything fine. Its called image-loader there I'm getting URL.

Download happen fine.  But image not display.

Comment: Pass context in new ImageLoader(this); use getApplicationContext instead of this. Try to show static in that imageview . first check is it working fine or not ?

Comment: static image was working fine.. download from URL image is not working.. if i getApplicationContext also not working